# Прижатый к низу div, пока окно развернуто

Tags: веб-программирование, позиционирование, javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с одной проблемой. Вообщем, у меня есть div, зафиксированный (fixed) внизу окна. Ясное дело, что уменьшать высоту окна браузера, этот div будет ехать вверх. Так и надо, но не совсем. div будет ехать до самого верха окна, пока  высота не станет минимальной. А мне надо, чтобы он остановился на определенной высоте от верха окна, например на 300px. Очень вероятно, что через css я этого добиться не смогу, так что js и jQuery будут с радостью приняты мной. Да, этого, в принципе, можно добиться при использовании зафиксированной невидимой таблицы высотой 100% и минимальной высотой 300px с этим дивом внизу, но этот вариант мне не подходит в связи с тем, что этот див должен быть выше всего остального содержимого страницы (z-index больше, чем у других) и если делать таблицей, то она, хоть и прозрачная, но будет перекрывать остальной контент. Вообщем, очень прошу помощи, буду очень благодарен тем, кто поможет.
P.S. Одна из идей - следить за изменением высоты другой таблицы, у которой будет минимальная высота 300px, и когда у нее будет эта минимальная высота, фиксировать див на высоте 300 от верху, иначе на высоте 0 от низа. Я не знаю, правда, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит делаем так.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

Внутри фунции проверяем размер окна и если оно меньше нужного размера, то меняем стиль у дива. Например убираем *position: fixed;*

**UPDATE**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
if (window.innerHeight < 300) {
    alert("Минимальный размер");
    document.getElementById("id дива").style.position = "relative";
}
    console.log(window.innerHeight)
}
```

Comment: Можно чуть-чуть подробнее? Я пока не знаком с js...

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сейчас попробую поднастроить)))